# Routing Event Hub messages to Azure funtion by message type

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've create an Azure Function to listen to an Azure IoT Hub instance. When I post message to the IoT Hub I set a property like so:

```
        Message iotMessage = new Message([myMessage]);
        iotMessage.Properties.Add("Type", [MessageType]);
```

At the Azure Function end I want the Azure function only to receive/process messages that have a Type property and where the Type property equals "MessageType1".

I cannot see a way to do this in an Azure function. Can someone advise if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** this appears to be what you're looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-process-d2c#add-a-queue-to-your-iot-hub-and-route-messages-to-it

Your condition would be Type=MessageType1 and you would have the function trigger off of the output queue.

---

What type of input binding are you using for your Azure Function?

AFAIK, this isn't currently possible in one step. However, there are a few options you have:

- connect IoT Hub to a ServiceBus Topic/Subscription, which allows you to do some filtering based on properties. Trigger on the subscription which filters by MessageType1
- have a function dedicated to filtering IoT Hub messages. When it matches a MessageType1 message, put that message into a queue. This queue triggers another function which only processes matched messages

Comment: My input binding is of type eventHubTrigger. I quite like the sound of option two, but how do I read the property associated with iotMessage? I'd assumed what I get passed in to the Azure Function was only [myMessage].

Comment: I think that you'll be able to use IoT Hub routing rules (see in the edited link above) to accomplish what you need -> filter by type property to post to your eventhub. If you want to go with the 2nd option, you'll have to test if the properties are passed (I don't know off the top of my head). If they aren't you could make the type a part of the message itself.

Comment: Using the routed endpoints as described link worked just fine thanks.